# Is there any way to shorten url by goo.gl by javascript

Tags: javascript, goo.gl

I want to add a button at my webpage, when I click the button it will try to locate goo.gl and input the current url.

How could I use goo.gl service by javascript?

### FYI:

I found somthing at here http://www.labnol.org/internet/create-google-short-url/11748/
but how to import this function?
var auth_token = getUrlShorteningRequestParams(url);

```
function shortify(url)
 {
  var auth_token = getUrlShorteningRequestParams(url);
  var urlEscaped = escape(url).replace(/\+/g,"%2B");

  xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://goo.gl/api/url?
     user=toolbar@google.com&url=" + urlEscaped
     + "&auth_token=" + auth_token, false);
  xmlhttp.onload = xmlhttpLoad;
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

### FYI again

check http://marcusnunes.com/api-goo.gl.php

Answer (score 1):

goo.gl's API requires a `POST` request to `http://goo.gl/api/shorten?url=URL`, which means you can't do it in pure content (in a regular web page) JavaScript.

I developed a [service](http://ggl-shortener.appspot.com/instructions/) that supports this using JSONP.  However, it's become a victim of its own success, and now frequently exceeds the App Engine quota.

EDIT: The JavaScript code you've posted is from a Chrome extension.  It can be done in privileged browser extensions; I wrote a similar [Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/55308/).

The PHP API also seems fine.  However, there is a new API (`/shorten`) that doesn't require the token.  Also, it doesn't seem to have a JSONP version for use with JavaScript.

Comment: Open a new window is ok,but the problem is user and auth_token, I want user can trace there shorten url.

Answer (score 0):

You can create short URLs on client side using bit.ly service:

[jQuery on the fly URL shortener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771397/jquery-on-the-fly-url-shortener/7005673#7005673)