# Automatic url shortening with a custom Twitter tweet button

Tags: javascript, twitter, url-shortener

Is there a way to make twitter generate a shortened version of my url when using a custom button (according to: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button#build-your-own).

I don't need any counters, I just want to share a text, shortened url and a hashtag.

```
var twUrl = 'http://twitter.com/share?count=none&text=' + encodeURIComponent(text) + '&url=' + url + '&hashtags=' + encodeURIComponent(hashtags);
    window.open(twUrl, 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=650,height=254');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the bitly API to shorten your url's.

Checkout the documentation: http://dev.bitly.com/get_started.html

See also this SO question with a code example in the answer on how to make use of the bitly API using  jquery:
[jQuery on the fly URL shortener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771397/jquery-on-the-fly-url-shortener)

Comment: So I will need to use the service manually first, and use the response in my code above?

Comment: See my updated answer. It has a link to a SO question that will guide you through the whole process.