# Why is this Bit.Ly script not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to use bit.ly api to automatically shorten URLs for my blog but this code does not seem to be working

```
<script>getShortUrl: function(url, callback)
{
   var url = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=***********************&longUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.techforty.com';

    $.getJSON(
        url,
        {},
        function(response)
        {
            if(callback)
                callback(response.data.url);
        }
    );
},</script>
```

Is there a quick and easy way to get short URL out of this script in an input box?

Comment: Did you write that JavaScript yourself? looks like the first line is wrong.  It should be: `var getShortUrl = function(...){...};`

Comment: no i found this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22064069/3404508)

Comment: i tried your edited code but this is also not giving a response

Comment: well, that's not properly syntax'd Javascript. did you get an error message?

Comment: but that's not the correct syntax...

Comment: then will you please provide the corrected code.

Comment: are you sure you're sing the right access token? try visiting `https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=bf7031d2185c52280234f585eaee8‌​69391025526&longUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.techforty.com`

Comment: yes this is demo [check](https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=bf7031d2185c52280234f585eaee869391025526&longUrl=http://www.techforty.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using this in an object. Here's the code

```
var App = {

getShortUrl: function(url, callback)
{

    $.getJSON(
        url,
        {},
        function(response)
        {
            if(callback)
                callback(response);
        }
    );
}
}

App.getShortUrl('https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=***********************&longUrl=http://www.techforty.com', function(response) {
    $('#result').html(response.data.url);
});
```

Comment: fiddle is just displaying empty <div id="result"></div>

Comment: i just want to display shortened url into a input box

Comment: open the console. it's getting the data. it's just not appending it cause its an object not a string

Comment: @Avadhesh18 check my answer again