# How to make a URL Shortener with the Bitly API with JavaScript JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I'm trying to make a URL Shortener tool for my web application using the Bitly API.

I found [an SO thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771397/jquery-on-the-fly-url-shortener/22064069#22064069) and saw what seemed to be simple enough jQuery solution.

```
getShortUrl: function(url, callback){
   var accessToken = //My access token, I've signed up at the site
   var url = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=' + accessToken + '&longUrl=' + encodeURIComponent(url);

$.getJSON(
    url,
    {},
    function(response)
    {
        if(callback)
            callback(response.data.url);
    }
);
},

alert(getShortUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=URL+Shortener+JavaScript"))
```

I'm testing this out in chromium dev tools. The code doesn't error but the alert always comes out as undefined.

Comment: What's the ajax response?

Comment: Funny, I look at the network panel and don't see anything. There's no error. But there's no listing of the URL I'm sending the call to.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the call and see if it's even being made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing a callback and you get `undefined` because `getShortUrl` doesn't return anything.

Try this:

```
getShortUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=URL+Shortener+JavaScript",
    function (url) {
        alert(url);
    }
);
```

Comment: You beat me to it by literally 19 seconds.

Comment: Yea sometimes it takes saying it out loud or maybe typing it all out and then you go oops i see now! =]

Comment: "Why doesn't my code work?"
"Why doesn't my code work?"
"Why doesn't my code work?"
"Ahdasuiauhsdiausdhuahsdauishd"
"Oh. Missing a semi-colon"